# CSS for docking/sliding panel on a web page

Tags: jquery, css, panel, docking

I would like to display any validation error messages on a web form similar to compilation error messages in visual studio that slides up from the bottom when there are errors. the error message panel should overlay on top of the form without taking extra space and can be closed if required. how to achieve this with the help of CSS / jQuery or in any other way?

thanks,
Rama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site gives has detailed discussion on how to create a sliding panel using CSS, HTML and JQuery

http://theorangebelt.org/forums/showthread.php?t=1033

Comment: I need to try this out. but thanks to all for the replies anyway.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work , can you replace it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Zurb, their examples are creative and powerful:

[OS-X like dock by Zurb](http://www.zurb.com/playground/osx-dock)

By the way, I don't recommend any kind of dock, dock is not webapplication friendly ui element in my opinion.